# Show books of device that are missing in calibre

Tags: calibre, ebook-readers, sync

How can I show books that are on the device, but not present in the local Calibre library?

I have installed Calibre on multiple computers. Naturally, my eBook device ends up with the complete collection of eBooks. When the device is connected, it shows which books are already on the device, but not which ones are missing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Calibre is connected to a device, you may choose to view *books on the device*, as shown below. The first column, *In Library*, has green check-marks if the book is already in the PC Calibre library, as well as on the device.

Click on the column header for *In Library* to sort on that field. Then select the *unchecked* books and right-click to add to the local library.

BTW, on my PC's, I find moving more than a few hundred books at a time is far slower than the total time to move then in batches of 200 or so. Also, Wagnardsoft's [Intelligent standby list cleaner](https://www.wagnardsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1256) seems to help move large numbers of books more efficiently, at least on my PC's.

[image: Books in Calibre Library and on Device]